# Agregar items a un JComboBox en java

Tags: java, array, netbeans

Estoy agregando en array que previamente lo obtuve de una BD.
Pero al momento de meter el array al combobox me aparece con "[Ejemplo]"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Existe una forma en la cual no me aparezcan los simbolos []?
Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Tanto en las preguntas como en las respuestas, es sano poner el código como texto, pues se espera que los demás usen el código sin tener que transcribirlo desde una imagen, sea para ver el error que tienes o para probar tu solución sin introducirle errores en la transcripción.

Answer (score 0):

Para quien le interese es la forma en que se manda a llamar los campos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se utilizo la funcion que recupera la info de la BD (res) luego para obtener un string y el campo que esta entre comillas tiene que ser el nombre del campo que esta en la BD

Comment: Por favor, procura enviar capturas de pantalla. En su lugar copia y pega el código en tu respuesta y tras seleccionar el bloque de código pulsa en el icono `{}` para que tenga formato de código.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias intentar antes de que añada al dato al array colocarlo en una variable de forma String y le puedes modificar el nombre por defecto, leyendo caracter por caracter y quitando los que sean [] y devolviendo un String sin estos y esos si los añades en el combobox... podria ser? no se si sirva ese metodo poco ortodoxo me comentas saludos.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que tu respuesta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Sería mejor que agregaras un ejemplo de código que acompañe a tu explicación para que tu respuesta se entienda mejor.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).